# how to debug Minification failed. Returning unminified contents

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

I am using Asp.net MVC 4 bundler to bundle and minify my Css files.

YSlow is showing this error below

```
 /* Minification failed. Returning unminified contents.
    (1442,26): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found ':'
    (1442,26): run-time error CSS1042: Expected function, found ':'
    (1442,26): run-time error CSS1062: Expected semicolon or closing curly-brace, found ':'
     */
```

This is my bundle code,

```
    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
        "~/Content/site.css",
        "~/Content/fullcalendar.css",
        "~/Content/jquery.dropdown.css",
        "~/Content/jquery.tagit.css",
        "~/Content/tipsy.css"
        ));
```

Now how will i find out which css file is causing the problem ? How can i debug to find the line that is causing the problem ? site.css is the only css file that i wrote.

Comment: do you want to turn off minification?

Comment: no i would like to minify. Do you prefer to use third party tools like  css minfier than MVC bundler ?

Comment: try creating seperate bundle fro each file,then you can find for which file the minification is failing

Comment: thanks ! good idea i will try this  and will let you know !

Comment: It was in my css ! (1442,26): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found ':' is the error i see now, so does this mean i need to look at line 1442 in my css file ?

Comment: yes. check the line 1442 of the related css file, that is your problem.

Comment: For me, the problem was that the minifier didn't like Javascript arrow functions (e.g. `var s => { }`)

Answer (score 41):

In case someone is still dealing with problems like this.

In the example above: (1442,26) 1442 is the line number and 26 is the character offset. HOWEVER, for this to be exact, you need remove the whole comment where this error is indicated:

```
 /* Minification failed. Returning unminified contents.
    (1442,26): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found ':'
    (1442,26): run-time error CSS1042: Expected function, found ':'
    (1442,26): run-time error CSS1062: Expected semicolon or closing curly-brace, found ':'
     */
```

Comment: I found that happening on jQuery, installed by nuget...!? OK , I removed the min version and it sorted it. It seems like on debug=false, it tries to minify the minified version, it fails and returns garbage. Really strange. Removing all .min sorted it for me

Comment: It's not even the line numbers in the original file.  It's the line numbers in some expanded version of the file (i.e. the unminified output).

Comment: thanks... indeed found a "  --bs-tooltip-margin: ;" line in the output

Answer (score 2):

Here's two possible causes:

- The invalid CSS files that should be validated before bundling. here
  is [W3C CSS validation service](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator) to meet this purpose.
- Also considering that Microsoft Optimizer reads content of target
  resources for minification process, so by using some special phrases
  like `@ sourceMappingURL=jquery.min.map` in a JavaScript file or
  `@charset "UTF-8";` in a styleSheet file, the Minification will be
  failed again. So try to remove or commentize them.

**Note** that by default, Bundling process *can't build relative path of image resources* in css or js files.

**Relative Image Path Solution:**

You can use the same path as bundling path like:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css/jquery-ui/bundle")
       .Include("~/Content/css/jquery-ui/*.css"));
```

Where you define the bundle on the same path as the source files that made up the bundle, the relative path of image resources will still work( i.e. `/bundle` can be any name you like).

Or using `new CssRewriteUrlTransform()` as second parameter like:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css/bundle")
    .Include("~/Content/css/*.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform()));
```

Comment: Nice! I used the first relative image path solution, and it worked great.

Comment: The minifier and bundler were meant only for JavaScript files and stylesheets. These problems have nothing whatsoever to do with images.

Answer (score 1):

filter: alpha(opacity: 0); was the line that was causing the issue. After i removed this line
i was able to minify the css file without any issue,

Comment: Changing the tag to say opacity=0 rather than opacity:0 fixed this for me